# How to make menu links with include?

Tags: hyperlink, menu, include, dreamweaver

I'm making my website with include function so less have to bee downloaded. But I just can't remember how to make it the way I wan't.

I got a menu like this: Frontpage - Products - Prices - About us - Contact.

When on the frontpage and clicking the Products link I wan't the content of the Products page to show on the same page via the include, but how is it I do that? The content of the Products page and the other will of course just bee an empty file with some text.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, you can simply use `file_get_contents("FileYouWantHere");`. This will output the contents of that file. If that file is written in PHP too however, use `include("FileYouWantHere);`.

Comment: But with that, will I be able to view Frontpage, product, prices, about us and contact text on the same page?